# Data in a Service cleared on Page Refresh

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, scope, angularjs-service

Whenever the page is refreshed (Like with F5) the data in my service is cleared. Is there a way to fix this without local storage? It's not a crucial feature but the application breaks if you refresh the page and that's not typically the best for the end user...

First Controller:

```
$scope.go = function(location){
    classService.currentClass = location;
}
```

Service:

```
.service('classService', function () {
   var classService = this;

   //Init
   classService.currentClass = null;
});
```

Second Controller:

```
  .controller('ClassCtrl', function ($scope, classService) {
      var currentClass = classService.currentClass;
      $scope.className = currentClass.getTeacherClassName();
      $scope.classDescription = currentClass.getTeacherClassDescription();
      $scope.classCode = currentClass.getTeacherClassCode();
  });
```

It may be blatantly obvious but I'm a bit new to programming and AngularJS in general.

EDIT: I tried removing the null init and it **didn't** fix it.

Comment: Sounds like you need a backend. Localstorage is good, though. Why would you want to avoid it?

Comment: @AustinMullins I do have a backend, I'm looping through an array returned by it's REST API in another view and I'm trying to pass through the specific  item they clicked on. I wanted to avoid local storage because I just wanted something simple but I think a cookie might be the easiest way then.

Comment: because a cookie is so much simpler than localstorage..</sarcasm>

Comment: Your only real options are ngCookies or localStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very easy to implement $localStorage in angular using [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage)

please see demo here

http://plnkr.co/edit/F9dEP472n8ETaK1wLqVq?p=preview

Add ngStorage to your home page

```
<script src="http://rawgit.com/gsklee/ngStorage/0.3.0/ngStorage.min.js"></script>
```

Add ngStorage to your module

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['ngStorage']);
```

Add $localStorage service to your controller and service

```
angular.module('app').service('classService', function($http,$localStorage)..
```

the rest is in demo [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/F9dEP472n8ETaK1wLqVq?p=preview)